# Integrating Skype into a UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, skype, skype-for-business

I am working on a C# UWP application in which I need to integrate Skype For Business. I need to provide the following functionality: automatic log in, view users' statuses, send and receive chat messages, video call and share screen.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Just use Skype for business?

Answer (score 2):

There is no [official Lync SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn820099.aspx) out for WinRT or UWP apps, please see the suggestion in [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8216842c-8129-468a-bc0f-bc0795ffa247/lync-integration-with-windows-store-apps?forum=winappswithcsharp)